# Numba bad performance for a simple for loop (Python 3.10)

Tags: python, numba

my code:

```
from numba import njit
from functools import wraps
import time

def timeit(my_func):
    @wraps(my_func)
    def timed(*args, **kw):
    
        tstart = time.time()
        output = my_func(*args, **kw)
        tend = time.time()
        
        print('"{}" took {:.3f} ms to execute\n'.format(my_func.__name__, (tend - tstart) * 1000))
        return output
    return timed

@timeit
@njit
def calculate_smth(a,b):
    result = 0
    for i_a in range(a):
        for i_b in range(b):
            result = result + i_a + i_b
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    value = calculate_smth(1000,1000)
```

without the numba decorator my function completes in ~62ms, with njit decorates (after compiling beforehand) it needs ~370ms.
Can someone explain what I am missing?

Comment: What makes you say "after compiling beforehand"?

Comment: first time running this it takes 20 seconds, since the JIT needs to compile on first execution.

Comment: It definitely shouldn't take 20 seconds. Have you tried running `calculate_smth(...)` multiple times in the same script?

Comment: Here are the results of running your code with two calls to `calculate_smth` - `"calculate_smth" took 520.015 ms to execute; "calculate_smth" took 0.000 ms to execute`

Comment: Apparantly I am not fully understanding the JIT...
It needs to compile each time I run the python script? I was under the impression that it would compile ONCE on first running it and then it would not need to compile again until I change the code.

Comment: "*It needs to compile each time I run the python script?*" Yes unless you use caching (which is far from being perfect). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation . You might want to consider Cython instead (static compiler). Numba has an AOT compiler which is similar to the one of Cython but with many additional limitations making it not very interesting in practice. Note that eager compilation can be use to compile the function when the decorator is executed instead of when the function is run for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

JIT stands for Just-In-Time - meaning the code is compiled **at execution time** - as opposed to AOT - Ahead Of Time. As you can read in [Numba docs](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/jit.html), by default compilation is lazy, ie. it happens on the first function execution in a program.

It also supports AOT compilation, as described [here](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/pycc.html)

Another option would be `cache=True` parameter passed to `numba.njit` decorator.